# Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF' linebreak-style

Tags: reactjs, github, web-deployment

I cloned a website based on react js in my windows pc, on running **npm start** I got this error

```
Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
```

after looking some answers in stack-overflow on adding this line in my .eslintrc

> "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],

website started to work fine.
This is my .eslintrc file from cloned repo

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": ["error", {
      "components": ["Link"],
      "specialLink": ["to", "hrefLeft", "hrefRight"],
      "aspects": ["noHref", "invalidHref", "preferButton"]
    }],
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
    "no-console": ["error", {
      "allow": ["warn", "error", "info"]
    }],
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/destructuring-assignment": 0,
    "react/function-component-definition": [2, { "namedComponents": "arrow-function" }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
    }],
    "react/jsx-no-useless-fragment": 0,
    "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": [1, {
      "declaration": true,
      "assignment": true,
      "return": true
    }]
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

**Query**

On deploying this website on github it is showing this error again
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"endOfLine": "auto"` setting in `.eslintrc.js` and `.prettierrc` files.

So, file `.eslintrc.js` should have:

```
rules: {
    /*  ...the other code is omitted for the brevity */
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': [
        'error',
        {
            endOfLine: 'auto', /* this setting should be included */
        },
    ],
```

And file `.prettierrc` should have:

```
{
    /*  ...the other code is omitted for the brevity */
    "endOfLine": "auto" /* this setting should be included */
}
```

Comment: Error : Definition for rule 'prettier/prettier' was not found  prettier/prettier

Comment: @Amish try to [apply these solutions](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/20) to resolve this error